# Assigning Eigen Block to a Matrix gives wrong elements

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

When I'm using block method of Eigen Matrix and assigning the return values to the MatrixXd variable itself , the element of the matrix changed weirdly.

Here is a simple example to reproduce this problem.

```
  Eigen::MatrixXd temp(3, 5);
  temp << 60, 1.44583e-14, 2.90553e-14, 59.9308, 60, 
          60, 60, -2.90553e-14, 0.140057, 80, 
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  std::cout << "Temp:\n" << temp << "\n";
  std::cout << "Temp.block(0,0,2,5):\n" << temp.block(0, 0, 2, 5) << "\n";
  temp = temp.block(0, 0, 2, 5);
  std::cout << "Temp=Temp.block(0,0,2,5):\n" << temp << "\n";
```

the output would be like

> Temp:
>
> > ```
> >    60  1.44583e-14  2.90553e-14      59.9308           60
> >    60           60 -2.90553e-14     0.140057           80
> >    1            1            1            1            1
> > ```
>
> Temp.block(0,0,2,5):
>
> > ```
> >   60  1.44583e-14  2.90553e-14      59.9308           60
> >   60           60 -2.90553e-14     0.140057           80
> > ```
>
> Temp=Temp.block(0,0,2,5):
>
> > 4.64591e-310      1.44583e-14     2.90553e-14      59.9308            60 
> > 4.64591e-310               60    -2.90553e-14      0.140057           80

Just like the output of the code the first column changed after the assignment.
I know it is better to create a new MatrixXd to get the block but I just want to know why this kind of situation happens?

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for `Eigen::MatrixXd::operator=(const Eigen::MatrixXd&)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the left side aliases the right side of the assignment. In general, Eigen does not guard against this in the interest of performance. Exceptions are made for matrix multiplication, where the `noalias()` method indicates that you, the programmer, has made the assessment. You can read the [Aliasing chapter in the manual](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html).

Under the hood, you requested an assignment with resizing. So the assignment operator allocated new memory. At this point the Block references a dangling pointer to the old, released memory. The memory allocator uses part of that memory for its own metadata. That is what you see in the first two entries.

To shrink to the top left corner without reassignment, please use the `conservativeResize()`.

In more general expressions where you know aliasing is an issue, use the pattern `leftSide = rightSide.eval()` to separate the computation from the assignment. Performance will suffer slightly.